# $F$ a field and $G$ finite subset of $F \setminus \{0\}$ with 1 & satisfying $a, b ∈ G$ then $ab^{−1} ∈ G$. Show that $G$ is cyclic

Tags: abstract-algebra, field-theory, finite-fields, cyclic-groups

Let $F$ be a field and let $G$ be a finite subset of $F \setminus \{0\}$
containing $1$ and satisfying the condition that if $a, b ∈ G$ then $ab^{−1} ∈ G$.
Show that there exists an element $c ∈ G$ such that $G = \{c^i : i ≥ 0\}$.

This is an excercise from the book: The Linear Algebra a Beginning Graduate Student Should Know; Golan

Comment: Your changes were not exactly equivalent then, seeing that the whole $F \setminus \left\{0\right\}$ isn't always cyclic (try $F = \mathbb Q$).

Comment: The claim in the question's title is false in general: neither $\;\Bbb Q^*\,,\,\,\Bbb R^*\;$ , etc. are cyclic. It is true though if $\;|\Bbb F|<\infty\;$ .

Comment: Do you mean $F$ is a finite field?

Comment: @Timbuc It's true *if and only if* $F$ is finite. The multiplicative group of an infinite field is never cyclic: if the field has characteristic $0$ it contains $\mathbb{Q}$; if it has characteristic $p>0$ it contains elements of multiplicative order $p^2-1$ that do not exist in the infinite cyclic group.

Comment: Did you mean to write $ab^{-1} \in G$ and not $ab^-1 \in G$, and, later, $c^i$ instead of $c_i$?

Comment: Maybe the problem is wrong cause by the conditions we have $1,b\in F\Rightarrow 1^{-1}b=1b=b\in G$ so $F=G$, isn´t it?

Comment: Are you sure you didn't mean to say: "$G$ is a finite subset of $F\setminus \{0\}$ and satisfying the condition if $\color{red}{a,b\in G}$ then $ab^{-1}\in G$"? Because the problem as you wrote it does indeed imply $F=G$, for which the problem doesn't hold when $F=\mathbb Q$.

Comment: I think it make sense, I get the problem from Golan's Linear algebra, so I have that doubt, thx, I gonna try with that condition.

Comment: Golan indeed has a typo there. (Exercise 28 in Chapter 2.)

Comment: @egreg Thanks for that, but why and how do you choose elements of order $\;p^2-1\;$ ? I'd go as follows: if $\;\Bbb F\;$ is infinite of characteristic $\;2\neq p>0\;$, then it contains the prime field $\;\Bbb F_p\;$ and here there's an element $\;1\neq a\in\Bbb F_p^*\;$ for which we have $\;a^{p-1}=1\;$ , so $\;\Bbb F^*\;$ has non-trivial torsion elements and thus cannot be cyclic. For $\;p=2\;$ I'm stuck.

Comment: @José With the last change you did to your post the question is "simply" to prove that a finite subgroup of the multiplicative group of a field is cyclic...though the wording is funny.

Comment: yea, I was thinking that too, So lets try that, thax to everyone.

Comment: @Timbuc A typo. I was trying to avoid the special case of $p=2$. Anyway, a field of characteristic $p>2$ contains elements of order $p-1$. If it has characteristic $2$, either it contains an algebraic element over $\mathbb{F}_2$, which has finite multiplicative order, or it is a pure transcendental extension of $\mathbb{F}_2$ and the group of invertible elements is not cyclic.

Answer (score 1):

By the classification theorem for finitely generated Abelian groups, $G$ can be written as the direct sum of some number of cyclic groups $G = \bigoplus_i \mathbb{Z}_{q_i}.$ Now, if $\gcd(q_i, q_j) = 1$ then $\mathbb{Z}_{q_i} \oplus \mathbb{Z}_{q_j} \cong \mathbb{Z}_{q_i q_j}.$ So, if the $\{q_i\}$ are all coprime, then $G$ is cyclic and we are done.

So, assume there are $n$ and $m$ such that $n\neq m$ and $\gcd(q_n, q_m)\neq 1.$ Therefore, there is a prime $p$ and elements $g, h \in G$ such that $g^p = h^p = 1$ and there is no $i$ such that $g^i = h.$

Note that for $1\leq k < p$, $$\sum_{i=0}^{p-1} g^i = g\left( \sum_{i=0}^{p-1} g^i\right) = \sum_{i=0}^{p-1} g^{ik} = 0$$ and so, by fiddling around with symmetric polynomials, you can verify that $$f(x) = x^p - 1 = \prod_{i=0}^{p-1}(x - g^i)$$ for all $x\in F.$ But, $f(h) = 0$ and this implies that the RHS of the equation is also $0$, but this implies there are zero divisors in $F$, which is false, and $G$ must be able to be written as a cyclic group.

Comment: Why is, in your argumentation, $1+g+g^2+\cdots+g^{p-1}=0$ ? I know it must be so since the elements $1,g,\dots,g^{p-1}$ are all zeros of the polynomial $X^p-1$ and therefore must be **the** zeros of $X^p-1$. So, $$X^p-1=(X-1)(X-g)\cdots(X-g^{p-1})$$ and expansion of the RHS gives that $\sum g^i$ is the coefficient of $X^{p-1}$ in $X^p-1$ hence must be $0$. However, your argumentation seems to be the other why round.

Comment: Notice that the sum, $S$, is such that $gS = S$. Now, if $S$ had a multiplicative inverse, this would be impossible, unless $g=1$, but we know that is not the case, so $S$ has no multiplicative inverse, so it must be $0$. As for taking the argument in the other direction, you could, if you have the remainder theorem proven, or something similar. But I wanted to prove it with the fewest results I could, and I think its worth making these sorts of observations.

Comment: @user24124 OK, thanks a lot for clarification. But this way you still have to "fiddle around" with symmetric polynomials. BTW, what is the "remainder theorem".

Comment: Ok, I think I know what "remainder theorem" means. Once more, thanks for clarification. (Unfortunately I missspelled your name in my previous comment.)

Comment: The remainder theorem states that if a polynomial $p(x)$ is such that $p(a)=0$, then $p(x) = (x-a)q(x)$. To use this you need to know that $F[x]$ is a Euclidean ring, which may or may not have been covered. Otherwise, you're assuming that the factorisation techniques you learnt in the reals work in a general field, and that's not obivous imo. You don't really need to mess around with symmetric polynomials either, you can write down the coefficients in terms of sums of powers of $g$, and then simplify them. Either way works fine, but if you have Euclidean division, you can just use that.

Answer (score 1):

Let $G$ be a finite subgroup of the multiplicative group $F^\times$ of a (not necessarily finite) field, $\vert G\vert =n$ and let $d\mid n$; then $F^\times$ contains at most one subgroup $H$ of order $d$ since every element  $h$ of $H$ must be a solution of $X^d-1=0$ and there are at most $d$ such elements in $F^\times$. Hence, for each divisor $d$ of $\vert G\vert$ the abelian group $G$ can have at most one subgroup of order $d$; this is sufficient for $G$ to be cyclic (for example, by the classicifaction of finite abelian groups).

Edit: one can, in fact, avoid the use of the classification of finite abelian groups. One has to show that, if $G$ has prime power order, say $\vert G\vert= p^k$, then $G$ is cyclic. $G$ consists of the $p^k$ distinct zeros of $X^{p^k}-1$. The elements of $G$ which have order smaller than $p^k$ must have order a divisor of $p^{k-1}$. But these are zeros of $X^{p^{k-1}}-1$ and there are at most $p^{k-1}$ such elements. Hence there must be elements which have order $p^k$.